# What do the various PCS upgrades do?

Tags: xcom-2

When one buys a PCS upgrade at the Black Market, one can only see the name of it; it's only after purchase, at the stage of equipping it, that the game tells us what it actually does.

What PCS upgrades are available, and what do they do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From what I understand, each PCS has three variants: Normal, Advanced and Superior. Each tier is better than the previous one. Within each tier there can be some small variation. E.g. in the picture below, you'll see three Superior Agility PCS that have different Dodge stats.

This is a list of all the types available in the vanilla game:

- **Agility**: Increases the dodge stat. A better dodge stat will make more shots "graze" the character, greatly reducing the damage that it dealt.
- **Focus**: Increases the will stat. A better will stat will defend against psi-attacks, such as insanity, or mind control.
- **Conditioning**: Increases the HP stat. HP, or hitpoints, is the amount of health a soldier has. A soldier that is reduced to 0 hitpoints will die or bleed out.
- **Perception**: Increases the aim stat. Aim is used to calculate how much chance you have of hitting a shot.
- **Speed**: Increase the mobility stat. The mobility stat dictates how much meters you can move in a single move, which correlates to 1 square per 1.5 meter. Dashing is a full 2 moves. See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/256151/how-does-mobility-stat-correspond-to-tiles-moved-per-action) for more information.

[image: Equip a Personal Combat Sim]

Comment: Is speed not the amount of moves you can do per _action_ as opposed to per turn?

Comment: @Flater It is apparently more difficult than that. I'll update my answer.