# How does Mobility stat correspond to tiles moved per action?

Tags: xcom-2

X-COM operatives have Mobility 12, but they don't move 12 tiles.
In 1 action they can move 8 tiles in a straight line, or dash for 16 tiles.

Answer (score 13):

Looking at ini files (defaultgamecore.ini, line 1508 and defaultgamedata_soldierskills.ini, line 144), there are also meters and unreal units:
1 tile = 96 unreal units
1 meter = 64 unreal units
So 1 tile = 1.5 meters

So Mobility is in meters per action.

Examples (using Legend stats):

- 12 Mobility = 8 tiles (X-COM without PCS, basic enemies)
- 13 Mobility = 8.6 tiles (X-COM with PCS Speed+1)
- 14 Mobility = 9.3 tiles (Stun Lancer Mark1, Faceless)
- 15 Mobility = 10 tiles (Psi Zombie, Stun Lancer Mark2&3, Chryssalid, Berserker without enrage)
- 16 Mobility = 10.6 tiles (X-COM With PCS Speed+3 and GTS bonus, Sectopod)

Fractional speed adds up for dashes and diagonal movement.

Comment: Good answer. Having a mobility stat that just says how many tiles a unit can move would be much more useful. I wonder why they implemented this so counter intuitive from a gameplay perspective, but its probably due to programming/engine reasons and internal calculations.

Comment: Could be for balance reasons, to create more variety of unit speed with smaller increments. Or realism, 1 unit taking a square of 1.5x1.5 meters makes more sense than 1x1 meters. Personally I would prefer if they displayed speed in tiles, even if it meant showing fractional tiles. But at least all data is open in ini files so we can figure these things out ourselves.

Comment: Can somebody explain why this results in one tile less, in range, in XCOM EU/EW? See: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90424/what-do-distance-units-mean 

Was this a rounding error?